# Regex Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I want who my controller return only strings who respect (^[A-Za-z0-9]*|[a-z]|[0-9]|[.,-,*]), but when i execute, return all

```html
@empresas = Buss.where('atv = ?', 'S').where.not(tk_po: :tk_po.match(/(^[A-Za-z0-9]*|[a-z]|[0-9]|[\.,\-,\*])/) )
```

Comment: The `tk_po: :tk_po.match(/(^[A-Za-z0-9]*|[a-z]|[0-9]|[\.,\-,\*])/)` clause is going to resolve to `tk_po: true` because what you're doing is testing your regex against the symbol `:tk_po` not the value of that column.  You either need to figure out how to write regex for your database and build some sql to do that or filter the results in ruby *after* the database results come back.

Comment: your query is converted to something like `SELECT * FROM busses WHERE atv = 'S' and tk_po != 'tk')` If you want the database to filter by a regex then please check the DB docs for the specific syntax

Comment: Thanks to all, also i have to use REGEXP from mysql!

Comment: You should do this in a scope/method on the model which you then call from the controller so that you can test it isolation.

Comment: can I just add that your regex has redundant bits in it: `(^[A-Za-z0-9]*|[\.,\-,\*])` would do, as the "lower case latter" and "single digit" are covered by the first.  do also note that because of the use of `*` in both (which equates to "0 or more" this will match everything!

Comment: Thanks to all, i want mark this question as resolve!